Create infinite Reconciliation loop for a deployment with Kubebuilder
I am creating a controller that will watch a dpeloyment and its pods on a cluster. The watched deployment is not a custom resource. I have built out the controller with kubebuilder.  For the purpose of this, the deployment is called "foo" in the namespace "bar" I have set up the SetupWithManager function to look like this
func (r *DeploymentReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    namespace := "foo"
    deployment:= "bar"
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        Owns(&appsv1.Deployment{}).
        For(&appsv1.Deployment{}, builder.WithPredicates(predicate.Funcs{
            CreateFunc: func(e event.CreateEvent) bool {
                //fmt.Println(e)
                return e.Object.GetNamespace() == namespace && e.Object.GetName() == deployment
            },
            UpdateFunc: func(e event.UpdateEvent) bool {
                //fmt.Println(e)
                return e.ObjectNew.GetNamespace() == namespace && e.ObjectNew.GetName() == deployment
            },
            DeleteFunc: func(e event.DeleteEvent) bool {
                //fmt.Println(e)
                return e.Object.GetNamespace() == namespace && e.Object.GetName() == deployment
            },
            GenericFunc: func(e event.GenericEvent) bool {
                return e.Object.GetNamespace() == namespace && e.Object.GetName() == deployment
            },
        })).
        Complete(r)

This causes the reconcile loop to only work when events occur on "foo" and "bar". If my reconcile loop doesn't update anything within the deployment object, the loop stops running. I want the loop to run forever even if the controller considers the state to be "reconciled". Right now I've found a way around this problem by adding the following code to my reconcile loop.
...
    if val, ok := testdeploy.Labels["foo"]; ok && val == "bar" {
        testdeploy.Labels["foo"] = "blah"
    } else {
        testdeploy.Labels["foo"] = "bar"
    }

    err = r.Update(ctx, testdeploy)
    if err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }

This causes the reconcile loop to loop infinitely because the deployment is always updating.
I need the reconcile loop to constantly loop without stopping. Is there a better way to get around this issue or does this go against the design of what a controller should be?

The Controller should run continuously but Reconciliations should effect some mapping in a cluster's (namespace's) Resources from some initial state to some definite desired, end state and then complete. An infinite loop during Reconciliation is an undesired condition in which this transformation is never effected. It is possible that you're attempt to use a Controller for this purpose is problematic. Could you not use a simpler client that loops forever doing what you need?

To schedule periodic re-queuing, use the RequeueAfter attribute within the ctrl.Result object that you're returning from your reconcile method:
return ctrl.Result{RequeueAfter: 5 * time.Minute}, nil

It will requeue the request after the specified delay.
This approach is appropriate for actions that depend on external conditions that may change over time.
